# Identifying the recursion conditions for Python String

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I have this string `0123456789` and I want to use recursion to create a method that returns

```
'09182736455463728190'
```

So basically the above says that first I get the first num from the left and then the first from the right, and add them to the string, then I get the second from the left and the second from the right, etc.

When I reach the middle, I start adding to the final string the values of the initial string, but now int the opposite order. So `546372`, etc. So Starting from the edges I add first the most left and then the most right element.

Starting from the middle and moving to the edges, I favour the right side element first.

I cannot come up with the recursion relationship

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use recursion to handle this, you'd better try to solve it from top-down like this

```
def rec(nums):
    if len(nums) == 0:
        return ''
    elif len(nums) == 1:
        return nums * 2
    else:
        first = nums[0]
        last = nums[-1]
        return ''.join([first, last, rec(nums[1:-1]), last, first])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    nums = '0123456789'
    print(rec(nums))  # 09182736455463728190

    nums = '012'
    print(rec(nums))  # 021120

    nums = '0'
    print(rec(nums))  # 00
```

Comment: What's the point of the interior function? You're just forwarding the argument to it, so you might as well just use it as the recursive solution.

Comment: Just a practice, cause you can do other things like validation in the rec, _rec means the core of the rec function

Comment: Menglong, but it doesn't make sense. `_rec` has exactly the same parameters as `rec`, it is not closing over any local variables from `rec`, and `rec` passes its only parameter to `_rec` as an argument. `res` is equally senseless.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is.  The base case is when the final string length is twice the original string length.  This signals the end of recursion and returns the final string.  The recursive step consists of advancing the start index forward and the end index backward on the original string:

```
def transform_sequence(original, final = '', start_index = 0, end_index = -1):
    #base case:
    if len(final) == 2* len(original):
        return final
    #recursion
    final += original[start_index] + original[end_index]
    return transform_sequence(original, final, start_index + 1, end_index - 1)


print(transform_sequence('0123456789'))
#output: 09182736455463728190
```

Answer (score 0):

Fun problem and great way to learn about recursion. We can use [inductive reasoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) to ensure our program is valid for all input strings -

1. if the input `s` is empty, return the empty result
2. (inductive) `s` is *not* empty. get the first and last characters, `a` and `b`, and prepend/append them to the result of the sub-problem, `s[1:-1]`

We can easily encode this in python -

```py
def first_and_last(s):
  return (s[0], s[-1])

def puzzle(s):
  if not s:
    return ""                                # 1
  else:
    (a,b) = first_and_last(s)                # 2
    return a + b + puzzle(s[1:-1]) + b + a
```

We can see it working below -

```py
print(puzzle("0123456789"))
print(puzzle("12345"))
```

```
09182736455463728190 
152433334251
```

---

When then puzzle input is an odd length, notice how the middle character is repeated *four* times. When we reach the sub-problem `puzzle("3")`, `a=3` and `b=3`, and the result of `a + b + puzzle("") + b + a` is `3333`.

If you wish to handle this situation differently, we could modify `puzzle`

```py
def puzzle(s):
  if len(s) < 2:          # <- if input is empty or singleton string
    return s              # <- return s
  else:
    (a,b) = first_and_last(s)
    return a + b + puzzle(s[1:-1]) + b + a
```

```py
print(puzzle("0123456789"))
print(puzzle("12345"))
```

```
09182736455463728190 
152434251                 # <-
```

The nice answer from Menglong Li presents another option for dealing with puzzle inputs of an odd length. I encourage you to see it :D

Comment: Here's an even simpler one: `rec = lambda s: s[0] + rec(s[-1:0:-1]) + s[0] if s else s` (or `s and s[0] + rec(s[-1:0:-1]) + s[0]`, if you prefer that style).

Comment: "simpler" or "golfed"? Why not post an answer? I don't see how it's relevant to my post

Comment: I'd say simpler, since the recursion just does one element at a time. At least, that was the goal. It was inspired by your post, that's about the only relevance.

Comment: I'm sincerely delighted to inspire your work. Yes it handles one element at a time but at the cost of reversing the input string once per recursion. This is a puzzle problem so I suppose talking about efficiency is rather pointless. It's an entirely different process that I think deserves it's own answer and so I'd encourage you to post it ^^

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a different approach to this problem and assume the argument is a *sequence* rather than a `str`.  This simplifies our logic, allowing us to pass `str` to the initial call, but the recursive calls can pass `list`:

```
def puzzle(sequence):
    if len(sequence) > 1:
        first, *middle, last = sequence
        return first + last + puzzle(middle) + last + first

    return sequence[0] if sequence else ""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(puzzle("0123456789"))
    print(puzzle("12345"))
    print(puzzle("012"))
    print(puzzle("0"))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
09182736455463728190
152434251
02120
0
>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you approach this as processing the first character (placing it at the beginning and end) and recursing with the inverted remainder of the string then your exit condition will be an empty string:

```
def mirror(S):
    return "" if not S else S[0]+mirror(S[:0:-1])+S[0]

print(mirror("0123456789")) # 09182736455463728190
```

If you want to avoid generating new (inverted) strings on every recursion, you could also implement it using an index that you carry along and map to alternating start/end relative positions:

```
def mirror(S,i=0):
    j = (i+1)//2 * (-1)**i
    return S[j]+mirror(S,i+1)+S[j] if i<len(S) else ""
```